# Invest 100k in the Short Term Until It Could be Used to Buy an Investment Real Estate Property

Tags: real-estate, interest-rate, index-fund

I have a little more than 100k in my savings account. I have been keeping (and accumulating) that money in the savings account hoping to invest it in some kind of an asset (real estate etc.). However, I have been unable to find something solid to buy (an investment property for example) for some time and the 100k in my savings account is not making any money for me. What would be the best way to invest it, in stocks for example, so that, the investment is low risk, but would give me a higher return than keeping the money in the savings account? I believe, I could invest in an index fund, however, when I find the ideal property, I would need to use that money to buy that property; in that case, if my money was invested in an index fund, will I be able to take the money out when I need to make a purchase?

Comment: You probably should talk to a professional investment advisor, or at least educate yourself on diversification and how to evaluate investment risks. Whether you can withdraw from the fund depends on the conditions of the funds. Many have certain minimum holding periods, many don't.

Comment: How soon will you need to use the money? If it is less than 3-5 years I wouldn't invest it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sold one house but not planning on buying another for several months. What to do with the funds?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/111298/sold-one-house-but-not-planning-on-buying-another-for-several-months-what-to-do)

Comment: UK version with more view: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/119041/best-ways-to-invest-for-a-planned-house-purchase-in-1-year/119045

Comment: @base64, yes that answers the question. However, the best money market accounts at the moment only give a 0.6 return